# Android Detect Package Installer Has Started

Tags: android, installation, package

My goal is to temporarily disable my service when someone is installing a new apk file. There are a couple of receivers related to the package installer such as after install and after uninstall shown below, but I haven't found one that will trigger when the package installer opens.

```
    <receiver android:name=".PackageInstallerReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

There also doesn't seem to be a good solution to detect when an app is opened or else that would be an easy solution.

Any Ideas?

Comment: There is no official way to do this. Some "App Protector" apps use to read the logcat to get info like this but now I'm not sure what they do since permission changes for reading logs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might be mistaken but it seems Lux is able to temporarily disable itself when the package installer is opened.

Comment: What is Lux? This? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux&hl=en

Comment: Yes. The app will return sub zero brightness to 0 and turn night settings off when the package installer opens, and go back on after the package installer finishes.